# Updating a ObservableCollection on another Site/Update Button

Tags: c#, sqlite, mvvm, uwp

I am developing a UWP app with SQLite and I am facing an issue and I would like some help - because Right now i just found a bad solution.

I have a collection of Movies which are saved in my DB as a `string FavMoviesIdString` (every favorite Movie's `ID` is added to the string and splitted by `";"` - because you can not save whole Lists of MoviesModels)
The user can review those Movies via a FavMoviesCollection on a different Site (Site B).

The method `LoadMovies` gets those Movies and displays them in `FilteredMoviesList`. (It binds to a ListView `Mode=OneWay`)

If the user opens Site B the first time, the `LoadMovies` method gets called in the Constructor and all the Movies are displayed, **BUT**, the User can add Movies to their Favorites from Site A after visiting Site B . The Issue: The List does not update after the Movies has been added on Site A.

Open App -> Go to Site A and add a movie to Favorites -> Go to Site B - The movies gets displayed -> Go back to Site A and add another Movie -> Go back to Site B and only the first Movie is displayed.

*"What do I have to do, that the List updates if another Item is added"* **or** *"What can I do to reinitialize my Constructor?"* **or** *"Should I implement a Update Button to manually load the Movies?"*

```
public ObservableCollection <MovieModels> FilteredMoviesList
    {
        get { return _filteredMoviesList;}
        set 
        {
            _filteredMoviesList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FilteredMoviesList")
        }
    }

    public void LoadMovies()
    {
        using(var db = new DataBaseContext())
        {
            ObservableCollection<MovieModel> movies = new ObservableCollection<MovieModel>();
            movies = DatabaseModel.GetSampleFavMovies();
            FilteredMoviesList = movies;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: What works right now:

On navigating to another Page I call the `LoadMovies` method - so only after leaving the site the list updated and that is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is a good example of when to use messaging in MVVM.

When the users add Movies to their Favorites from Site A, you should send a message. B should register for this message and do its own action.

The use messaging you can use the *Publish/Subscribe pattern*. To do this you do not have to implement it. You can use several MVVM librarys that implements is.

For example you can use MVVM Light:

Inherit your ViewModel from `ViewModelBase`, then you have a `MessengerInstance` that you can use to send and register for messages.

Your code in AViewModel (when users add Movies to their Favorites):

```
MessengerInstance.Send(new FavouritesListChangedNotification());
```

Your code in BViewModel (in consturctor):

```
MessengerInstance.Register<FavouritesListChangedNotification>(this, scn => {/* here imlement you action when in site A the list of favorites changed*/});
```

FavouritesListChangedNotification is your own class that can contain other information, for example the list of movies.

This way you avoid having direct references between ViewModels that will result in loosely coupled ViewModels and thus more easily maintainable client code.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the thing is was looking for!